# Classification prediction with ML for longitudinal data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science, lstm

I have a project I'm working on, I'm not allowed to give the actual example so I'll use a proxy example.

We have data for a number of driving students over many months.

For each observation (student and month) we have recorded a number of variables e.g hours spent learning, IQ, household income etc. and a dummy variable which is true if the student passed their test in that month and false if they did not.

I would like to use all of this data to predict for the future months the likelihood that a student will pass in that month.

e.g For the next 6 months we should know in any given month how likely it is that any given student will pass their test.

My initial research suggests that LSTM might be the best approach. I'm hoping to use Python, could anybody point me in the direction of some first steps or guidance?

other points to note:

- students may begin learning at any time
- having passed a test, the student will no longer be recorded

Comment: Did you spend some time doing data analysis before modeling? Can you really feel that there is a need for "sequential" understanding (hence the suggestion of LSTMs) from your samples to predict that likelihood? I can see that you have a mixture of features, some are sequential (monthly timestamped) while others should be constant over the whole period (IQ, household income): am I mistaking?

Comment: @Arnaud I did yes, there are some fairly clear trends with some of the indicators particularly the sequential ones. Other factors e.g income or IQ were included as I felt there may be some interaction effects.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very wide question. Here's my analysis on it.

**Problem setup**

A supervised classification problem is a matter of `X`s and `y`. In your case, if I understand well, here's an example of `X` and `y`:

- `X` contains all available static and sequential data for a given user:

```
X = [iq, income, time_spent_m-2, time_spent_m-1, time_spent_m]
     - static -  -------------------- sequential -------------
```

/!\ Different users will have different historical data. Keep in mind you'll have to decide one fix vector size (say M=15) you want to use anyway, and practice *padding*.

- `y` is a probability distribution over next 6 months, trying to figure out when the student will pass the test:

```
y = [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]  # should sum to 1?
```

--> `X` is of varying size, while `y` is of fixed size.

**Training data**

You can take advantage of all the users that did and did not pass the test as training datas. And that, translated, for every month. If you usually collect data from users for more than six months, there'll typically be a lot of `y`s that are thus [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], which means **your final layer can not sum to one** as I assumed earlier. Caution, the training data can be a little unbalanced (many zeros, very few ones).

**Model**
LSTMs is indeed a model suited for sequence-to-sequence relationships. There are plenty of tutorials online to get started with them according to the framework you choose. Famous frameworks for deep learning in Python are [Keras](https://keras.io/) (on top of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)) and [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/).

Hope that helps.